# Load iframe and reset document location at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

Load iFrame and reset document location at the same time.

I'm making a video album for a DVD present to family members. The video's will be displayed in an iFrame similar to YouTube's, with thumbnails below representing the various videos.

I've got the videos loading into the iFrame correctly, but I can't seem to get the `onclick` function to work more than once to bring the iframe back into to viewing position when I get to the bottom rows of the video thumbnails.

I'm very new to using JavaScript and can't seem to figure out how to make both events happen at the same time, load the new video and bring the iframe back into it's original viewing position.

Here's the code I'm using to change the frames which works flawlessly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadsource() 
{ 
var defaultPage = "../vpages/video.htm";
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var pos = query.indexOf('=');
   if (pos > 0) 
   {
      var frameSource = query.substring(pos+1);
      window.frames["frameBox"].location = frameSource;
   }
   else
   {
      window.frames["frameBox"].location = defaultPage;
   }
}
</script>

<body onload="loadsource()"/><iframe id="frameBox" name="frameBox" 
class="aligncenter" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Here's the code I attempted to use with the a href on click function that works flawlessly (only once per page load) which I need to somehow work into the original frame loading code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function toFrame(){
       document.location=document.location+'#videotop';
    }
frameBox.onload=toFrame();
</script>

<a href="../vpages/video-21.htm" target="frameBox" onclick="return toFrame();">
<img alt="video" src="../images/default(21).jpg" width="120" height="90"    class="imgTxtCntr"/>description here</a>
```

I know it must be very easy for someone who knows what they're doing with JavaScript, but for me at this time, it's extremely frustrating as I don't yet have enough knowledge to build my own scripts, and have not successfully been able to marry the code into one script or figure out how to circumvent the `onclick` problem.

Help! How do I put the document location function into the `onload` function and bypass the `onclick` problem and bring the iFrame window back into the viewable portion of the screen on load?

Comment: Do you have a link to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but what I got is this:

You have a page with an iframe at the top.There are many links, going down;

If someone clicks on one of them, the chosen video loads into the iframe

```
<a href="..." target="framebox" onclick="return toFrame();">
```

Also, there is the `onclick` which will call `toFrame()` to "scroll" the page back up again.
I think if you just place an anchor like

```
<a name="topOfPage" id="topOfPage" />
```

before your iframe and change your toFrame() function to be

```
function toFrame(){
    location.hash = "#topOfPage";
}
```

It should always scroll up to there.

**EDIT**:

Ok, I looked at it again, recreated it in html files and found the following to work *for me*:

```
function toFrame() {
    location.hash = '';
    location.hash = '#videotop';
}
```

It seems to be important to reset the location to empty, otherwise it wont scroll.
Now you're welcome :) (I hope this works for you)

Comment: @Geoffrey Burdett 
(I do not have a link to the page, it's being built local for use on a DVD, as the initial question states.)

Comment: **@Palatiner** The original question also shows the anchor #videotop in the toFrame() function, and as far as I can tell, "location.hash = "#topOfPage"; basically does the same thing as the original coding of the toFrame() function, so by making the suggested change, the onclick problem persists and so does my dilemma.

The basic problem is that the **onclick no matter how I code it, scrolls the page back to the anchor only on the 1st click** on any of the group of linked thumbnail images.

Comment: On any successive clicks on the same or other thumbnail links, the video loads but the document does not scroll back to the anchor above the iframe. 

How do I load the video and scroll back to the anchor **without using the onclick, which** apparently **works only ONE TIME per page load.**

Comment: Really, all I need to know is how to put function 'loadsource()' and function 'toFrame()', or their equivalent, into the same script so that it loads the iframe and scrolls the document back to the anchor above the iframe when the href tag is clicked. Can anyone help?

Comment: You could try to get rid of the ``<a href="../vpages/video-21.htm" `` completely and make it call a modified version of ``loadsource()`` in an onclick attribute. See if that works more than once and you might gain some insight. Also, you should try debuggin you javascript. If you don't want to bother with breakpoints, just but the line: ``debugger;`` anywhere you want to break and attach the javascript debugger. What browser do you use anyways?

Comment: **@Palatiner ** I've tried this code in Chrome, Firefox and IE10 with the same results in all browsers.

I don't know how to use a debugger yet, as I'm still working on my first "Hello World!" JavaScript!

I'm just stumbling through finding code snippets I can piece together to make my wife happy by finishing this project that she dreamt up. What do you mean by a modified version of loadsource()?

Comment: Based upon what I've been able to learn about the onclick attribute, it seems like many people have the same problem of the onclick firing only once per page load. Isn't there a way to call the iframe load and the #anchor from the same script without using the onclick attribute?

I see it happening on other pages on the internet, but it's buried deep in special js coding that I can't figure out.

Thanks for your attempt to help me get through this.

Comment: You should definitely look into jQuery. It will make your life *so much* easier. Forget the "modified version" of that function. Go jQuery! It will make your wife happy :D If you need help (once you figured out the basic stuff like selectors and events), I'll gladly be there for you!

Comment: Look at the anwer again, I changed it!

Comment: **Palatiner** Thanks for taking the time to look over the code again and make the revision to your first suggestion.  It now works in all three major browsers.  Now I can get on to learning JavaScript (in whatever free time I can redirect after I finish this project,) and actually code my first "Hello World!" script!  As I had originally suspected, the project was just a few simple lines of code away from the finish line.  It's amazing what you can  do with a little bit of specific knowledge. Thanks a bunch for all your help with this!